# @Autowired using AspectJ in spring does not work on first time server up

Tags: java, spring, aop

I am using **AspectJ** with **Spring 3**. I am autowiring bean using **AspectJ** `@Configurable` and `@Autowired` annotations. When I start the server (WAR in tomcat 8) for first time it shows null value for autowired variable.
If I restart the server then getting the autowired value.
The bean defination is done using **xml**.
Sample code:

```
package com.app;

@Configurable
public class Employee {
  @Autowired
  public Person person;

  public void doWork() {
    person.getName();
  }
}
```

application context settings:

```
<bean id="person" class="com.app.Person"></bean>
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:spring-configured/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.app"/>
```

#### Software config

- spring version: 3.2.13.RELEASE
- spring aop version: 3.2.13.RELEASE
- aspectjweaver : 1.8.6
- Using apache tomcat 8 with java 8.

I do want to be able to run server first time without getting null pointer exception.

Answer (score 0):

I found that if at the time of bean creation and spring boot if the class is instantiated then the auto wiring will not happen and it will give null values for auto wired beans.
The temporary solution is to use check of null values and instantiate the object again.

```
public class Employee {
  @Autowired
  private Person person;
  private static Employee instance;

  public static Employee getInstance() {
    if (instance == null || instance.person == null) {
      instance = new Employee();
    }
    return instance;
  }
}
```

This actually uses singleton design pattern and if the person is not autowired creates new singleton object.